# PHP | How to loop pages with custom numbers?

Tags: php

I got help in a previous post, My PHP:

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
for ($x = 0; $x <= 100; $x++) {
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page".$x);
}
?>
```

Now I need to loop a custom numbers, instead of 1 to 100, I want to loop these numbers:

```
'570','12','190','18'
```

How i do it please?

Comment: Are you sure this works `file_get_contents("http://website.com&page".$x);`?

Comment: @kerbholz Yes, it works without a problem. But the url is not real: website.com

Comment: Ok, just thought `&` should be a `?`, but if it works, it works.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$a = ['570','12','190','18'];
foreach( $a as $i ) {
    // $i is your number
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use foreach.

```
foreach ([570, 12, 190, 18] as $number)
{
    var_dump($number) // 570, 12, 190...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
<?php
set_time_limit(0);
foreach([570, 12, 190, 18] as $x) {
file_get_contents("http://website.com&page".$x);
}
?>
```